# Regex selection not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a script that automatically formats the script for a teleprompter. It is supposed to capitalize everything (with certain exceptions). However, it should also leave anything in angled or square brackets alone, as well as parenthesis.

Here is the code I created:

```
<script>
String.prototype.smartUpperCase = function(){
    var pattern = /(.*?[a-z][A-Z])(.*)/g;
    if(pattern.test(this)){
        return this.replace(pattern,function(t,a,b){
            return a+b.toUpperCase();
        });
    }
    else{
        return this.toUpperCase();
    }
}
String.prototype.regexEscape = function(){ return this.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"); }
String.prototype.removeBrackets = function(){ return this.replace(/[\<\>\[\]\(\)]/g, ""); }
String.prototype.format = function(returnValNoShow){
    text = this;
    orig = text; // for use in multi-line regex pattern
    text = text.replace(/(\w+)/g,function(t,w){ return w.smartUpperCase(); }); // smart uppercase everything
    text = text.replace(/\d{1,2}[st|nd|rd|th]{2}/gi, function(m){ return m.toLowerCase(); } ); // for dates (1st, 2nd, etc. will be lowecase)
    // complicated regex -> find anything inside <>, [], () and inject the original string back in
    var pattern = /.*(?=[^\<]*\>|[^\[]*\]|[^\(]*\)).*/g;
    text = text.replace( pattern, function(match){
        console.log(match);
        if(match==""){ return ""; }
        var pattern2 = new RegExp(".*(?="+match.regexEscape()+").*", "gi");
        //console.log(orig.match(pattern2));
        return orig.match(pattern2)[0];
    });

    text = text.replace(/\&/g, "AND"); // switch & for and

    text = text.replace(/ +/g, " "); // replace multiple spaces with one
    text = text.replace(/\n{3,}/g, "\n\n"); // replace 3+ line breaks with two
    text = text.replace(/\}\n{2,}/g, "}\n"); // don't allow empty line after name
    text = text.replace(/\n{2,}-+\n{2,}/g, "\n---\n"); // don't allow blank line between break (---)

    text = text.replace(/\n /g, "\n").replace(/ \n/g, "\n"); // trim() each line

    text = text.trim(); // trim whitespace on ends
    return text;
}
function f() {
    document.getElementById("in").value = document.getElementById("in").value.format();
}
</script>
```

And the HTML that is simple enough:

```
<textarea id="in" rows="40" cols="80">{NAME}
THANKS ____ AND ____. AS WE REPORTED LAST MONDAY, BATMAN VS SUPERMAN: DAWN OF JUSTICE CAME OUT THIS PAST WEEKEND AND IT SET SOME BOX OFFICE RECORDS.

{NAME}
(DDR) That's right ____. 'Batman v Superman' took huge $170 million at the box office. Audiences flocked to see the pairing of Batman (Ben Affleck) versus Superman (Henry Cavill) in the DC Comics film, which also introduced Wonder Woman (Gal Gadot).

{NAME}
IT'S THE BIGGEST MARCH OPENING WEEKEND EVER, EVEN BEATING 2012'S THE HUNGER GAMES' WHO BROUGHT IN $152.5 MILLION.

{NAME}
IN OTHER NEWS - SYRACUSE IS THE FIRST 10 SEED TO MAKE IT TO THE FINAL FOUR.

(ad lib)
</textarea>
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="f()" value="Format"/>
```

99% of the time this works as expected. However, as is shown with the second paragraph, it sometimes doesn't do anything.

(The text in the textarea has already gone through the formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that your "find stuff in brackets" regular expression:

```
var pattern = /.*(?=[^\<]*\>|[^\[]*\]|[^\(]*\)).*/g; //wrong
```

is matching the *whole string*: the pertinent part of the pattern is enclosed in a "lookahead" assertion that is zero-width and only serves as a boolean yes/no. You need to actively match these sequences in a consuming pattern (while also not eating the rest of the string by getting rid of the `.*`), so that they can be replaced properly:

```
var pattern = /(\([^\(]*\)|\{[^\{]*\}|\[[^\[]*\])/g;
```

This issue is encountered again when you build your replacement pattern with which to match against the original text:

```
var pattern2 = new RegExp(".*(?="+match.regexEscape()+").*", "gi"); //wrong
```

this again looks ahead to see `match`, but it's surrounded with `.*` wildcard sequences, so if there's a match at all, it'll be the *whole string*. change this to:

```
var pattern2 = new RegExp(match.regexEscape(), "gi")
```

now when you do the replace, it works like you want it to...[this demo shows your code working as intended](https://jsfiddle.net/jvp7x0jv/7/).